# Blender and Python script. Error when I press "run script" button but it work as expected

Tags: python, scripting, animation-nodes

As the subject i have a script that is working as expected while the "run script" button report an error. Is this normal? Thanks in advance

[image: Blender 3.3.1]

Comment: The text block is evaluated in the context of animation nodes, if you execute it as a  standalone script, the variables will not be initialized

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer. :)